# Find bases given that P is the change of coordinates matrix from this to this [Lay P244 Q4.7.19]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Lay P289: Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space, let $W$ be an $m$-dimensional vector space, and let $T$ be any linear transformation from $V$ to $W$. To associate a matrix with $T$, choose (ordered) bases $B$ and $C$ for $V$ and $W$, respectively.

$$
[T(x)]_{c}= [[T(b_{1})]_{c}\ [T(b_{2})]_{c}\ \cdots\ [T(b_{n})]_{c}] [x]_{B}
$$

$19.$ Let $ P= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1\\
-3 & -5 & 0\\
4 & 6 & 1
\end{bmatrix}, $
$ v_{1}=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-2\\
2\\
3
\end{array}\right\},\ v_{2}=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-8\\
5\\
2
\end{array}\right\},\ v_3\ =\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-7\\
2\\
6
\end{array}\right\}
$

**Textbook Question (a) :** Find a basis $\{u_{1},\ u_{2},\ u_{3}\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $P$ is the change-of-coordinates matrix (I post the definition below) from $\{u_{1},\ u_{2},\ u_{3}\}$ to the basis $\{v_{1},\ v_{2},\ v_{3}\}$.

**Textbook Answer :** If $C$ is the basis $\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}$, then the columns of $P$ are $[u_{1}]_{C},\ [u_{2}]_{C}$, and $[u_{3}]_{C}$. So $u_{j}=[v_{1}\ v_{2}\ v_{3}][u_{1}]_{C}$, and $\color{forestgreen}{ [u_{1}\ u_{2}\ u_{3}]=[v_{1}\ v_{2}\ v_{3}]P }$.

> $1.$ I know that in part (a),  $P$ is given as $[ .. [u_{i}]_{C} ...]$, but what's the proof strategy? How do we proceed with this? I omit all calculations; I'm not asking about them in any of my questions herein.
>
> $2.$ Whence does $ \color{forestgreen}{ [u_{1}\ u_{2}\ u_{3}]=[v_{1}\ v_{2}\ v_{3}]P }$ originate? It doesn't look like the formula at the start of my question?

**Textbook Question (b):** Find a basis $\{w_{1},\ w_{2},\ w_{3}\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $P$ is the change- of-coordinates matrix from $\{v_{1},\ v_{2},\ v_{3}\}$ to $\{w_{1},\ w_{2},\ w_{3}\}$.

**Textbook Answer :**  Analogously to part $a.,\ [v_{1}\ v_{2}\ v_{3}]=[w_{1}\ w_{2}\ w_{3}]P$, so $[w_{1}\ w_{2}\ w_{3}]= [v_{1}\ v_{2}\ v_{3}]P^{-1}$.

> $3.$ I know that in part (b), P is given as $[ .. [v_{i}]_{W} ...]$, but what's the proof strategy? How do we proceed with this?

Comment: What is the definition of a "change of coordinates matrix"?

Comment: It does not strike me that the linked page obeys the same conventions as this question.  In particular, the page puts the change of basis matrix on the left of any vectors it transforms.  This question puts the change of basis matrix on the right.

Comment: @Muphrid I've included the definition in the book. Does this help?

Comment: At some point, you just have to read the proof carefully and understand the individual steps; asking for (or expecting) intuition on every little result is not really reasonable at this stage.

Comment: Definition of change of coordinates: ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/d5CM4.png

Answer (score 2):

I will only address the $2^{nd}$ part of the first question.

> 1. Whence does $[u_1\;u_2\;u_3] = [v_1\;v_2\;v_3]P$ originate? It doesn't look like the formula at the start of my question?

Writing something like $[u_1\;u_2\;u_3] = [v_1\;v_2\;v_3] P$ and putting $P$ on the right is "correct" and actually makes perfect sense!

Given any two "abstract" real vector spaces $V$ and $W$ of dimension $n$ and $m$ respectively.
Let $B = ( b_1, b_2, \ldots b_n )$ be a basis for $V$ and 
$C = ( c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_m )$ be a basis for $W$.
For any $x \in V$, the $[x]_B = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ appear in the start of question isn't an element in $V$. Instead, it belongs to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and relates to $x \in V$ through a relation of the form:

$$x = x_1 b_1 + x_2 b_2 + \cdots + x_n b_n$$

The matrix $P = (p_{ij})_{\substack{i=1..m\\j=1..n}}$ associated with a linear transform $T : V \to W$ is defined in a similar manner. Let's say 
$$[T(x)]_c = (y_1, y_2,\ldots,y_m) \in \mathbb{R}^m \iff T(x) = y_1 c_1 + y_2 c_2 + \cdots + y_m c_m.$$
An expression like

$$[ T(x) ]_C = \Big[[T(b_1)]_C, [T(b_2)]_C, \ldots, [T(c_n)]_C\Big][x]_B$$

should be interpreted as
$$y_i = \sum_{j=1}^n p_{ij} x_j\quad\text{ for } i = 1,\ldots, m\tag{*1}$$
where $p_{ij}$ is the $i^{th}$ component of $T(b_j)$ in basis $C$.

When $V = W$ and hence $n = m$, one can associate a matrix $P$ to the identity transform
$V \ni x \xrightarrow{id} x \in V = W$ in above manner. This is the change of coordinate matrix.

Since $p_{ij}$ is the $i^{th}$ component of $b_j$ in basis $C$, we have

$$b_j = \sum_{i=1}^m p_{ij} c_i\quad\text{ for } j = 1,\ldots, n\tag{*2}$$

Notice the summation is now over the left index $i$ of the matrix $P$. 
When a matrix form of this relation is needed, some authors prefer to write this simply as $b_j = ( c P )_j$. They do this in order to stress which index of $P$ is summed over. 
One can summarize all these relations of different $j$ in a single matrix relation. Namely,
the one that you are confused about:

$$[b_1\;b_2\;\ldots\;b_n ] = [ c_1\;c_2\;\ldots\;c_n ] P\tag{*3}$$

The key to remember is

- In the definition of $P$ in $(*1)$, what is summed over are coordinates of a given vector and we sum over the right index $j$ of $P$.
- In an expression like $[u_1\;u_2\;u_3] = [v_1\;v_2\;v_3] P$ or that in $(*2)$ or $(*3)$, what is summed over are vectors in $V$ and the sum is over the left index $i$ of $P$.

Finally, there is one advantage in the convention used in $(*3)$. If you represent everything in a common basis and identifies the $b_i$, $c_j$ to their components/coordinates in that common basis. You can view them as ordinary column vectors.
$(*3)$ becomes an matrix equation among 3 ordinary $n \times n$ real matrices.