# Find a change of basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $P$ is the coordinate matrix from $B$ to the basis $C$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

[image]

In the solution, it simply multiplied $C$ and $P$ respectively.

I don't understand this because the problem states $P$ is the change of coordinate matrix from $B$ to $C$, so I thought that I would need to take the inverse of $P$ and left multiply it with $C$ to find $B$.

I'd appreciate explaining how to go about solving this and why the solution was right multiplication the $B \to C$ matrix.

Thanks

Comment: Can you answer the question in the hint?

Comment: The columns of P(B->C) are the columns of B in the C basis I believe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find bases given that P is the change of coordinates matrix from this to this \[Lay P244 Q4.7.19\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811423/find-bases-given-that-p-is-the-change-of-coordinates-matrix-from-this-to-this-l)

Answer (score 1):

In order for $P$ to be the change of coordinate matrix from $B$ to $C$, it needs to hold that the columns of $P$ are the coordinates of the basis vectors of $B$ regarding $C$.

In particular: it must hold that

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} = \lambda_1^1\boldsymbol{v_1} + \lambda_2^1\boldsymbol{v_2}+\lambda_3^1\boldsymbol{v_3} = \lambda_1^1 \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} + \lambda_2^1 \begin{pmatrix} -8 \\ 5 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} + \lambda_3^1 \begin{pmatrix} -7 \\ 2 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} $$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -5 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} = \lambda_1^1\boldsymbol{v_1} + \lambda_2^1\boldsymbol{v_2}+\lambda_3^1\boldsymbol{v_3} = \lambda_1^2 \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} + \lambda_2^2 \begin{pmatrix} -8 \\ 5 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} + \lambda_3^2 \begin{pmatrix} -7 \\ 2 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} $$

$$\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \lambda_1^3\boldsymbol{v_1} + \lambda_2^3\boldsymbol{v_2}+\lambda_3^3\boldsymbol{v_3} = \lambda_1^3 \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} + \lambda_2^3 \begin{pmatrix} -8 \\ 5 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} + \lambda_3^3 \begin{pmatrix} -7 \\ 2 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} $$

where $$ \boldsymbol{u_i} = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1^i \\ \lambda_2^i \\ \lambda_3^i \end{pmatrix}$$